# How to get keyword subfields from AWS Open Search using SQL API

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

Am using AWS Open Search server ,end point v1.0.0

I have created a sample table and declared the text columns with "keyword" type as below:

```
"mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "color": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In default mapping, you can see the type as both text and keyword.

But while retrieving column information using Open Search SQL API, only text type fields are returned from API like the below-mentioned image.
[image]

I need ".keyword" fields from the AWS Open Search server.

But the same case in Elastic search server return fields including the ".keyword" fields

Please share any idea to get ".keyword" fields from the AWS Open Search server